# how to keep php Class method in a variable

Tags: php

1.here's my wrong code

```
class classname{
    function __construct(){};
    public function test(){return 0;};
}

$c = new classname();
$test = $c->test;
var_dump($test); //out put NULL, I want the method $c->test
```

**I didn't want to execute the function and store the result**

there is something wrong with my code.
howto write it!

---

here's the code what I wanted(by **Bobot**):

```
$test = function() use ($c) { return $c->test(); };
```

---

**devmyb**'s answer was helpful,and he/she told me why my codes not works

---

*Bobot* 、*JezEmery* 、*devmyb* ... etc

thanks for your help

Comment: `$test = function() use ($c){ return $c->test(); };` then when you need it : `$test();` But this is the wrong way I guess ..... Or maybe you just want to execute the function and store the result ? => `$test = $c->test();`

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is to store the property `test` in the variable `$test` you can try

`$method = 'test'; $test = $c->$method();`

Comment: thanks,a lot! this is a way to solve my questions! But Bobot's answer is I wanted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but **I guess** you want to do this :

`$test = function() use ($c) { return $c->test(); };`

Then when you need to run your method, just run the function : `$test();`

I guess that [some documentation about anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) can help you to understand the code.

Comment: yes,this is my question! does it a wrong way to keep class method in a variable?

Comment: Well, once you instantiated a class, why doing all of this when you just need to do `$c->test();` ? If you think you need it, you are probably right, I haven't your code under eyes, but that's looking to be a paradigm...

Comment: this right! there's something wrong with mac's default php! but when i change it to linux ! it works well! thks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You're not calling the function, you're trying to access a property (which isn't found).

```
$test = $c->test();
```

That should work.

Comment: I just want to keep  a class method in a variable, not the class method result! thks all!

Answer (score 2):

Its because you didn't have your `error_reporting` `on` else you'll get the notice, warning and fatal error too

You have typographical errors, check the updated code

```
class classname{
    function __construct(){} // removed ;
    public function test(){return 0;} // removed ;
}

$c = new classname();
$test = $c->test; // You were calling variable of your class
$test1 = $c->test(); // You were calling method of your class i.e.  public function test()
var_dump($test);
var_dump($test1);
```

**Output:**

```
Notice: Undefined property: classname::$test in /in/HBNf9 on line 9
NULL
int(0)
```

Comment: yes,but i want to keep a class method in a variable,how to ? thks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code. After a function is no ;

```
class classname {

        function __construct(){

        }

        public function test() {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    $c = new classname();
    $test = $c->test;
```

Comment: please follow my questions!

Comment: I did't want to ask syntax error! I want to keep a class method in a variable

Comment: Well you have the same syntax error since your code is exactly the same apart from the formatting.

Comment: The question has been edited since I put the answer.

Comment: Before: "__construct(){};"

Comment: The original question stated - Here is my wrong code ...
....
.....
There is something wrong with my code. How to write it?
I found a syntax error and I posted the code without the syntax error.

http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41279294/1

Comment: @Michael ,I say there's something wrong were logic,not a syntax error!